# Get ID of subcategory in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress I wanted to crate category in following manner

> Electronics->Computers->Data Storage

so first i have to check if category exists or not for that i used
     `$cat_id=get_cat_ID($catname)`,
it gives category id of Electronics if it exits if not i will create this category and get its id like this

```
 wp_insert_term($catname,'category',array('description'=>$cat[$i],'slug'=>sanitize_title($catname),'parent'=>$p));
$cat_id=get_cat_ID($catname)
```

next I have to create subcategory Computers under Electronics for that I used

```
$subcat_id=get_cat_ID($subcat_name)
```

but this always returns 0 if subcategory exists or not. How can I get the ID of a subcategory in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

According to the codex:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID

The function `get_cat_ID()` requires a string.

> **Parameters**
>
> $cat_name
>
> (string) (optional) Default is 'General' and can be any category name.

Your variable `$cat_name` is an array

```
$cat_name=array('cat_name'=>$cat_name);
wp_insert_term($cat[$i],'category',array('description'=>$cat[$i],'slug'=>sanitize_title($cat[$i]),'parent'=>$p));
$cat_id=get_cat_ID($cat_name)
```

To make  this work you either need to delare `$cat_name` like so:

```
$cat_name = $cat_name;
```

Alternatively change `$cat_id` to

```
$cat_id = get_cat_id($cat_name['cat_name']);
```